# dotnet not generating unsigned apk

Tags: android, .net, apk, maui, android-app-bundle

I have a Xamarin project which we are upgrading to MAUI which gets released to clients in 2 ways:

1. Playstore
2. MDM Servers

Some of our clients use there own MDM servers over which we do not have any control. All we do for them is give them an apk file.

MAUI recommends AAB format over APK for distribution through playstore.

My build command looks like this:

`dotnet publish "MyApp.sln" -f net7.0-android -c Release -p:AndroidKeyStore=true -p:AndroidSigningKeyStore="$SourceRoot/myapp.keystore" -p:AndroidSigningKeyAlias="MyAppKeyStore" -p:AndroidSigningKeyPass="androidKeyPass" -p:AndroidSigningStorePass="androidStorePass" -p:OutputPath="androidOutputPath" || exit 1`

This is creating 3 output artefacts: a myapp.aab, myapp-signed.aab and myapp-signed.apk

Previously, we used to run `zipalign` on the generated apk before signing it to optimize the apk. And then send it to MDM clients.

However, I do not have an unsigned apk here on which I can run zipalign and then sign and send it to clients.

How do I generate both an unsigned apk using my existing build command? The command should ideally generate 4 output files: signed and unsigned AAB, signed and unsigned APK.

I tried adding `-p:AndroidPackageFormats="apk;aab;"` but it seems it can only accept one value viz. either apk or aab. Not both.

Comment: Why do you want to call `zipalign` on the created APK file? zipalign is only necessary if some files are misaligned or if you use .so files that are not extracted on the device (but I would expect that if the MAUI build chain created a signed APK it has already aligned it before signing). If your application runs fine there is no need to apply zipalign on it.

Comment: @Robert could you please share where you read this. That MAUI build chain's signed apk already has files aligned. That's the exact purpose I want to use zipalign. But if not, I would need to know for sure that build process aligns the file already. Thanks!

Comment: That was simply a guess, if it does not correctly perform aligning before signing then this would be a bug (-> contact Microsoft), because aligning has to be performed before signing, otherwise it invalidates the signature.